# Creating MPI project on Eclipse Oxygen in Windows 10

Tags: eclipse, mpi

I've recently downloaded the lastest Eclipse IDE for C++ developer. I'm currently self-learning about MPI related programming.

Therefore, i downloaded the PTP package into my eclipse.

Next, i went to create a new MPI project via MPI C++ Project.

When i attempt to write my codes, i stumbled upon multiple MPI error such as

`unresolved inclusion <mpi.h>` and `Function MPI_Init cannot be resolved`.

I followed the PTP documentation accordingly and googled the error but it seems like MPI is not very often used on eclipse, therefore there isn't much assistance on such problem.

Does anyone know how to properly run a MPI project on eclipse oxygen?

Comment: First you should point eclipse to the MPI wrappers, for example, use `mpicc` instead of `gcc`

Comment: how do i do that? all the eclipse documentation for PTP are via the MacOS. I've been spending hours googling and figuring out how to run a proper MPI project via eclipse oxygen on windows 10